# Work and mechanical energy relationship for a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, work, rigid-body-dynamics

For a single particle in a conservative field, I know that the work done by an external non conservative force $W_n=\Delta M$ where $\Delta M$ is the total mechanical energy.

Is the same true for an extended rigid body?

If I've a rigid body and many forces are applied on it , Will the change in the total kinetic energy ( translation + rotation) be equal to the work done by these forces?

I couldn't find it in my textbook also I am getting wrong results when applying it here
[Apparent Inconsistency when analysing a spinning body set down to roll](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606440/apparent-inconsistency-when-analysing-a-spinning-body-set-down-to-roll)

Comment: The energy used to produce the work has to go somewhere.  Where else might it go?

Comment: Thank you dear garyp, I agree with you. I was in doubt because while solving a problem, I felt this rule was violated and hence believed that there might a subtle catch which I've missed out in rigid body dynamics.

Comment: This https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606440/