# Inconsistency in work-energy principle for a spinning body set down to roll

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, friction, rigid-body-dynamics

A spinning solid cylinder spinning with $\omega_0$ is put smoothly on a  plane. It will skid until it begins to roll with $\omega$

**Argument 1**

We know that, work done by all the forces assumed to act on the center of mass equals the change in kinetic energy of the center of mass.

The cylinder moves from $a$ to $b$, and the velocity of centre of mass changes from $0$ (when it was only spinning)  to $V_{cm}$ (when it has begun rolling). Therefore we can write

$W=\oint_{\mathbb{R_{a}}}^{R_{b}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{R}=\frac{1}{2} M V_{b}^{2}-\frac{1}{2} M V_{a}^{2}$

Using the above equation and  observing that only friction does work we can write the work done by friction until the body begins to roll is:

$$W_{f}=\frac{1}{2} m \cdot V_{b}^{2} -   0=\frac{1}{2} m \cdot \omega^{2} R^{2}$$

( I've used  $V_{b}=\omega R$ as the body begins pure roll after skidding
and initially $V_{a}=0$)

**Argument 2**

Also we know from the general work energy theorem that the work done on a body equals the change in total kinetic energy of the body, hence:

$W_f=\Delta K$ where $K=K_{translational}+K_{rotational}$

Using value of $W_{f}$ from argument **1** we have then

$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{m} \omega^{2} R^{2}=\left(\frac{1}{2} m \omega^{2} R^{2}+\frac{1}{2} I \omega^{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} I \omega_{0}^{2}$$

$\Rightarrow$ $\omega=\omega_{0}$

Which is incorrect.

Could anyone at least please hint where I'm going wrong. I have been thinking about it for more than  10 hours.

Comment: What are you trying to find ?

Comment: Dear Danny, I would be glad if I could find the flaw in the above deduction.

Comment: How can you equate translation work done to rotational work done+rotational work done?

Comment: I couldn't understand. Are you asking about the second equation?

Comment: Yes , i couldn't understand that .

Comment: Work done by the friction is the change in the total kinetic energy ( total means both rotational and translational)

Comment: It does but the left part only includes the change in linear KE.

Comment: The left part is $\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{m} \omega^{2} R^{2}=\left(\frac{1}{2} m \omega^{2} R^{2}+\frac{1}{2} I \omega^{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} I \omega_{0}^{2}$ , this is the energy when the body is just spinning

Comment: first, angular momentum is not conserved, friction makes a torque!

Comment: The first equation is wrong, you are not including neither the initial nor the final rotational kinetic energies

Comment: If we take our origin on the horizontal plane, then the torque of friction will be zero. Because $r$ and $f$ are along the same line.

Comment: Dear wolfram johnny you said "The first equation is wrong, you are not including neither the initial nor the final rotational kinetic energies" but from the previous post that you answered we know that $\oint_{\mathbb{R}}^{R_{i}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{R}=\frac{1}{2} M V_{b}^{2}-\frac{1}{2} M V_{a}^{2}$  . I only applied that here, and initially the body is only spinning so all its KE it's rotatinal

Comment: Your $W_f$ in argument 1 clearly can't be the total work done by friction, because friction does negative work overall. You are only accounting for the positive linear work done to increase the center of mass speed, not the larger, negative rotational work done to slow the rotation of the cylinder. If you include this work in your $W_f$ for argument 2, you see the two sides agree.

Comment: Thank you so much dear d_b it did clear it somewhat. You said that the total work of friction will be negative. How can that be? The friction acts forward the displacement of the skidding element is forward so $W=F.ds>0$

Comment: There are two components to the friction here, as I say in my answer. The friction that occurs at the point of contact with the plane (non-slip) is indeed acting in the positive direction. The *slipping* friction that occurs as the cylinder slides forward is opposing the motion, and therefore it is acting in the negative direction. See my answer for another picture of why this is negative (final - initial, and initial is greater).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here

> the work done on a body equals the change in total kinetic energy ... Using value of Wf from argument 1

$W_f$ is not the work done on the cylinder.

See in your calculation that you used $W=\oint_{\mathbb{R_{a}}}^{R_{b}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{R}$ where $\mathbf{R}$ is the position of the center of mass. This is calculating the confusingly-called "net work", which I prefer to call "center-of-mass work". This quantity does not represent the total change in kinetic energy, but only the translational part of it. Unfortunately, many authors are very sloppy about their presentation of the work energy theorem and do not clarify when and how it applies to extended objects.

To find the actual change in energy you need to use $W_i = \int \mathbf F_i \cdot \mathbf v \ dt$ where $\mathbf v$ is the velocity of the material of the cylinder at the point of application of $\mathbf F_i$. Note that during the time that the cylinder is slipping the force is in the opposite direction of this velocity, so the work is negative. Thus the final kinetic energy is less than the initial kinetic energy.

Comment: Thank you so much dear Dale.

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted my previous answer as it clearly didn't get to the heart of the issue for you. I'll try again:

Your first equation is the work done by friction during the *non-slip* portion of the motion, during which rotational kinetic energy is converted to translational.

You are forgetting the *skidding* portion of the problem, during which time the work done by friction is *not* equal to the final kinetic energy of the centre of mass.

There are therefore two "versions" of your first equation to consider:

$$ W_{f_{slip}} = \frac{1}{2}I(\omega^2 - \omega_0^2)$$ (this is the "energy lost to heat" that I was trying to remind you to include in my previous answer)

and

$$ W_{f_{non-slip}} = \frac{1}{2}mR^2\omega^2$$

By combining these, do you see that your contradiction/inconsistency no longer occurs?