# Contradiction in work-energy theorem for rigid bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, rotational-dynamics, work

We've a rigid body at rest. A force acts on it which leads it to translate (velocity of center of mass is $V_{cm}$ )and rotate about a fixed axis with $\omega$

Kleppner and Kolnekow prove that:

Work done by the force equals the change in kinetic energy of the center of mass.
So $W=\Delta K_{cm}=\frac{1}{2} m V_{c m}^{2}$ and here is their proof

> To derive the translational part, we start with the equation of motion for the center of mass
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mathbf{F} &=M \frac{d^{2} \mathbf{R}}{d t^{2}} \\
> &=M \frac{d \mathbf{V}}{d t}
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> The work done when the center of mass is displaced by $d \mathbf{R}=\mathbf{V} d t$ is
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{R} &=M \frac{d \mathbf{V}}{d t} \cdot \mathbf{V} d t \\
> &=d\left(\frac{1}{2} M V^{2}\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> Integrating, we obtain
> $$
> \oint_{\mathbb{R}}^{R_{i}} \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{R}=\frac{1}{2} M V_{b}^{2}-\frac{1}{2} M V_{a}^{2}
> $$

But we also know from work kinetic energy theorem that the Work done by an external  force equals the change in kinetic energy of the body so $W=\Delta K=\frac{1}{2} m V_{c m}^{2}+
\frac{1}{2} I \omega^{2}$.

Then these two equations contradict each other!

Can anyone please help me. I'm not able to sleep

Comment: The quote starts with "to derive the translational part". Why would you expect the rotation to be included?

Comment: Dear nasu,  The work done by external force equals the change in kinetic energy ( rot+trans)

Comment: This question was born due to another one here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606440/apparent-inconsistency-when-analysing-a-spinning-body-set-down-to-roll?noredirect=1#comment1365129_606440 Id be grateful if you could have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the force is applied at some $R$ above the CM, then $\mathrm{d}r=\mathrm{d}r_{\text{CM}}+R\omega \mathrm{d}t$, so you have an extra term. This extra term becomes:

$$ W_{\text{rot}}=\int FR\omega \mathrm{d}t=\int FR\omega \mathrm{d}\omega /\alpha=\tfrac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$

(where we replaced $\alpha=FR/I$ before integrating)

Comment: Thank you, say we've a spinning body spinning at $\omega_0$ set down on a horizontal plane and it skids and then begins to roll .The work done by friction is $W_{f}=\frac{1}{2} m \cdot V_{c m}^{2} -   0=\frac{1}{2} m \cdot \omega^{2} R^{2}$                But work done by friction will also be change in total kinetic energy which is $W_f=\Delta K\Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{m} \omega^{2} R^{2}=\left(\frac{1}{2} m \omega^{2} R^{2}+\frac{1}{2} I \omega^{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2} I \omega_{0}^{2}$.

Comment: But this is a contradiction, could you please have a look here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606440/apparent-inconsistency-when-analysing-a-spinning-body-set-down-to-roll?noredirect=1#comment1365129_606440

Comment: the question I answered is correct, now you are asking me a new and different question.

Comment: I have no problem on giving it a look though

Comment: Yes dear, I don't have any teacher to go to. I have only prayers to give you

Comment: I added two comments in your former answer, I hope it helps. But you can keep asking me there

Comment: Yes I'm studying your comment dear.

Answer (score 3):

If the line of action for the applied force does not pass through the center of mass, then the point of application of the force experiences a tangential acceleration. This means that for a given (short) time, the dR for the force is not the same as the dR for the center of mass.  This difference is not considered in the given derivation.  It is not valid if rotation occurs. Basically, the extra distance traveled by the force does the work to supply the rotational energy.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to work here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606440/apparent-inconsistency-when-analysing-a-spinning-body-set-down-to-roll?noredirect=1#comment1365129_606440