# Proof of work-energy theorem for a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, rotational-dynamics, work, rigid-body-dynamics

Could anyone show me a way to derive the work energy theorem
for a rigid body whose motion is along a fixed axis ( such as of a cylinder rolling on a plane) which states that
states that $W=\frac{1}{2} m V_{c m}^{2}+\frac{1}{2} I \omega^{2}$
using the basic definition that
$W=\int \vec{F} \cdot d r$.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606476/2451

Comment: can you give me please your comment on my answer. if you ask a question we need feedback to our answer!

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the EOM's:
\begin{align*}
&\textbf{Translation}\\
&m\,\ddot{r}_{cm}=F\\
&\dot{r}_{cm}\,m\,\ddot{r}_{cm}=\dot{r}_{cm}\, F\\
&\frac{m}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\dot{r}^2_{cm}\right)=\frac{d}{dt}{r}_{cm}\, F\\
&\int \frac{m}{2}{d}\left(\dot{r}^2_{cm}\right)=\int {d}{r}_{cm}\, F\\
&\frac{m}{2}\,\left(\dot{r}^2_{cm}\right)=\int {d}{r}_{cm}\, F\\\\
&\textbf{Rotation}\\
&I\,\ddot{\varphi}_{cm}=F\,R\\\\
&\text{analog}\\
&\frac{I}{2}\,\left(\dot{\varphi}\right)^2=\int {d}{\varphi}\, F\,R\\\\
&\text{thus work for the total energy $~T=\frac{m}{2}\,\left(\dot{r}^2_{cm}\right)+\frac{I}{2}\,\left(\dot{\varphi}\right)^2~$is }\\
&\int {d}{r}_{cm}\, F+\int {d}{\varphi}\, F\,R=
\int F\,\left(dr_{cm}+R\,d\varphi\right)=\int F\,dr\\
&\text{with}\\
&dr=dr_{cm}+R\,d\varphi
\end{align*}

Remark:

F is the constraint force between the cylinder and the plane and $~\dot\varphi=\omega$

Comment: Sorry dear Eli for my delayed response, I was caught up in some issues. Thank you for your response. I was however looking for a derivation that uses only the integral of $F.ds$ that would begin with it . You broke the integral from the beginning into two integrals which is not what I was looking for.

Comment: no problem, thank for your response, the last equation you see only the integral that you  are looking for?

Comment: Yes , can you explain it

Comment: you don't have only translation motion , you have translation plus rotation motion thus
$~dr\mapsto dr_{cm}+R\,d\varphi~$ see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606476/contradiction-in-work-energy-theorem-for-rigid-bodies